# "Use Strong Password" autofill does not meet webpage's password criteria: Is there a way I can change Keychain's autofill suggestion?

Tags: safari, password, keychain, monterey

Keychain suggested autofill password does not meet webpage's password requirement. Is there a way I can change the criteria of the autofill password feature to meet the requirements?

The password does not allow "-" and only allows specific set of characters.

Comment: I hate those sites who only ever test on Edge or Chrome. Unfortunately there's nothing you can do about it, except type some random string it *will* accept, or open Keychain Access & get it to generate on a different pattern. Keychain will save it whichever you choose.